# GIT bash showing "build failed" error in windows

Tags: git, bash, bitbucket, ssh-keys, git-bash

Trying to push the code to bitbucket (extremly new to bitbucket and the git world)

After creating the SSH key pair ,
as soon as i open the git bash, i get an error

`bash: cd: /git: No such file or directory`

followed by:
`Your build failed...`

OS :  windows 10

**UPDATE**:
For every command , i am also getting the following two errors:
`bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token)` 
`bash: command substitution: line 1: __git_ps1)`

Do ask if more clarity is required for the question

Comment: Are you calling git-bash.exe? (the 2.6.1 from https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: @VonC: Yes, I am using .exe

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to open the git bash by calling it with:

```
c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.1-64-bit\git-bash.exe
```

That will set HOME properly/

Make sure to call git-bash.exe from a regular CMD session, and not from other alternative shells ([which can have an issue](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/242#issuecomment-121151803))

Comment: Still i am getting the above mentioned 2 errors(mentioned in the update)

Comment: @dreamer What is your %PATH%? (when you are calling the git-bash.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem and solved it by completely uninstalling git bash and reinstalling the latest version from https://git-scm.com/download/win. I think the issue was that an older version had overwritten a newer version (via chocolatey).